# Nested loops not forming the full object - issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an `array of objects` like below:

```
[
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5634fa3df925a0ac02f1b0fa",
    "groupname": "group 1",
    "subgroups": [
      {
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "5634fa63f925a0ac02f1b0fc",
        "subgroupname": "subgroup 1",
        "books": [
          {                
            "bookname": {
              "name": "sasasasasasP"
            }
         }
        ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5634fa3df925a0ac02f1b0fd",
    "groupname": "group 2",
    "subgroups": [
      {
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "5634fa63f925a0ac02f1befc",
        "subgroupname": "subgroup 2",
        "books": [
          {                
            "bookname": {
              "name": "book 2"
            }
         }
        ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to form an `array of objects` like this below from the above object.

```
[
    {
        "groupname": "Group 1",
        "subgroupname": "subgroup 1",
        "bookname": "Enersol"
    },
    {
        "groupname": "Group 2",
        "subgroupname": "subgroup 2",
        "bookname": "Enersol"
    }
]
```

Below is what i tried, but the loop is failing after first object getting formed inside array.

```
var apiListData = [];
for (var i = 0, len = groups.length; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, len = groups[i].subgroups.length; j < len; j++) {
        for (var k = 0, len = groups[i].subgroups[j].books.length; k < len; k++) {
            apiListData.push({
                gname: groups[i].groupname,
                sname: groups.[i].subgroups[j].subgroupname,
                bookname: groups[i].subgroups[j].books[k].bookname
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a mongo object, are you using any sort of odm like mongoose? If so perhaps consider looking into getters and setters on the schema?

Comment: @jm_____: I am getting something like this and i would like to interate the array of object to form the new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/es47k33o/

There are multiple things wrong here:

1. The JSON structure you provided is quite messed up, its fixed in the fiddle
2. typo: there is a dot too much in `sname: groups.[i].subgroups[j].subgroupname`
3. to access the string value of a book name you have to get one level deeper than `bookname: groups[i].subgroups[j].books[k].bookname`
4. your actual algorithmic problem here is that you always redeclare the variable len. I renamed the second and third one according to their respective indexes:

```js
var apiListData = [];
for (var i = 0, len = groups.length; i < len; i++) {
 for (var j = 0, lenj = groups[i].subgroups.length; j < lenj; j++) {
  for (var k = 0, lenk = groups[i].subgroups[j].books.length; k < lenk; k++) {
   apiListData.push({
    gname: groups[i].groupname,
    sname: groups[i].subgroups[j].subgroupname,
    bookname: groups[i].subgroups[j].books[k].bookname.name
   })
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tcpdmmpp/) and see the browser console logs.

First of all, your `JSON` is corrupted, there is missing a `}` in each group, this is a valid one:

```
var groups = [{
    "__v": 0,
        "_id": "5634fa3df925a0ac02f1b0fa",
        "groupname": "group 1",
        "subgroups": [{
        "__v": 0,
            "_id": "5634fa63f925a0ac02f1b0fc",
            "subgroupname": "subgroup 1",
            "books": [{
            "bookname": {
                "name": "sasasasasasP"
            }
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "__v": 0,
        "_id": "5634fa3df925a0ac02f1b0fd",
        "groupname": "group 2",
        "subgroups": [{
        "__v": 0,
            "_id": "5634fa63f925a0ac02f1befc",
            "subgroupname": "subgroup 2",
            "books": [{
            "bookname": {
                "name": "book 2"
            }
        }]
    }]
}];
```

Besides the other issues in the code that @Stefan Dochow identified, it is always better to use variables to identify the objects in this kind of logic with nested loops. following is an example:

```
var apiListData = [];


for (var i = 0, totalGroups = groups.length; i < totalGroups; i++) {
    var group = groups[i];
    var subGroups = group.subgroups;
    for (var j = 0, totalSubGroups = subGroups.length; j < totalSubGroups; j++) {
        var subGroup = subGroups[j];
        var books = subGroup.books;
        for (var k = 0, totalBooks = books.length; k < totalBooks; k++) {
            var book = books[k].bookname;
            apiListData.push({
                groupName: group.groupname,
                subGroupName: subGroup.subgroupname,
                bookName: book.name
            });
        }
    }
}


console.log('apiListData', apiListData);
```